# I am try to under stand this javascript code but tired of it?

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body onload="myFunction()">
    <script>
    var go="globle";
    function myFunction() {
    var go="local";
    document.write(go);
         }
    document.write(go);
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

when I run this code it will print local.But when I run the following code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body onload="myFunction()">
    <script>
    var go="globle";
    function myFunction() {
    var go="local";
        }
    document.write(go);
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This code print globle.
Why not the first code printing both local and globle.
And also when I run first code my html body is also not executed.

Answer (score 1):

You are using document.write, which deletes everything when called.

> The write() method is mostly used for testing: If it is used after an
>   HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML.

Change it console.log(go) and you will see the expected output.

Comment: This isn't the issue here, document.write is never called for go="local" in the second example.

Comment: @Gerrit0 `document.write()` is an issue in the first example because the output should be `globallocal` and instead the OP is only getting `local` because the `global` output is being overwritten by the `local` output.

Comment: You are correct, sorry, apparently I misread the question and mistook it for a scope problem.

Comment: thanks @fafl for the help

Comment: *which deletes everything when called* Not necessarily true. `document.write()` will replace the existing document when that document has already completed being written to the client.  If the document is still being built, `document.write()` will append to it.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is flawed because of the use of `document.write`. When you use that AFTER a document has been built, it wipes out the earlier document and writes a new one. The results you were seeing from the first example were distorted by this.

Really, your examples are just demonstrating Global vs. Function scope in JavaScript. Anything declared with `var` in a function has local scope to that function and will be removed from memory when the function it is declared within terminates or is no longer held in memory.

Take a look at the comments I've added to your slightly modified code:

```js
// We are going to replace all the document.write() calls with
// console.log() calls because you are experiencing information being
// written to the document and then the document is being overwritten 
// with new information.

// The result will be "global, local" because the code in "myFunction" is
// not going to run until the window is loaded. The last line of code in 
// this example will actually run first.
window.onload = myFunction;

var go="global";  // Just declare a Global variable (available everywhere)

function myFunction() {
    // Declare a local variable, available only in the function
    // Since this variable uses the same name as the global one
    // when this function is executing, this variable will override
    // (hide) the other one.
    var go= "local";  
  
   console.log(go);  // The local one is used
}

// Now, we are outside the function and the local version of "go" is 
// out of scope. It's gone and can't be accessed. But, the global version
// is still available
console.log(go);  // The global one is used
```

Here's your second example:

```js
// Again, we're replacing document.write with console.log

// Even though we're calling the "myFunction" function when the
// window is loaded, that function only sets a local variable
// that will be destroyed when the function ends. It never does
// anything with that variable.
window.onload = myFunction;

var go="global";

function myFunction() {
    // This will be destroyed as soon as the function is done
    // which is the line right after it gets declared!
    var go="local";  
}

// Again, the scope of this line of code is global and so the global value is used
console.log(go);
```

Comment: thankx @ScottMarcus I got hte point